# Каким образом можно сделать такой слайдер?

Tags: вёрстка

подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать такой слайдер что бы самое главное он плавно перемещался. Пробовал через слик и работы с классами. Но работает очень топорно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://bkosborne.com/jquery-waterwheel-carousel

Comment: @MaximLensky Данный слайдер поддерживает и слайды с текстом? Т.е надо сделать слайд где фотография  + текст)

Comment: я не пробовал текст - хотя наверно поддерживает